# How to create a pipeline with SQL Server as an input driver in Google Cloud Data Fusion?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-data-fusion

I'm trying to ingest data from SQL Server database into Cloud Data Fusion, but after inserting a .jar file into SQL Server in HUB [image: .jar insert], the option doesn't appear to me in the pipeline-interface [image: no SQL Server option]. Is there anything else I must do to have the SQL Server as an option in the data pipeline interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL Server option is missing since you missed the step [Deploy the MS SQL Server Plugin](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/how-to/reading-from-sqlserver#deploy_the_microsoft_sql_server_plugin). Follow the steps below to deploy the plug in and the **SQL Server** option will appear.

In the Cloud Data Fusion web UI, click Hub in the upper right.

> Deploy the Microsoft SQL Server Plugin
>
> 1. In the search bar, type "Microsoft SQL Server Plugins".
> 2. Click Microsoft SQL server plugins.
> 3. Click Deploy.
> 4. Click Finish.
> 5. Click Create a Pipeline.

Deploy Microsoft SQL Server plugin:

[image]

After a successful deployment, it should be available at **"Studio"** and it is ready to use. See screenshot below.

[image]